# Incorrect understanding of buffer in RxJava

Tags: java, android, frp, rx-java

I'm trying to get familiar with RxJava. Here's the use case that i'm trying to achieve:

I have a button on my screen and i'm trying to collect the number of taps. So if a user taps the button, a click is registered and a log is produced. Now if the user clicks the button twice, then it registers both clicks, collects them and outputs 2 instead of 1.

Essentially, i'm trying to accumulate the number of clicks, over a span of time and then spit out the final results. I'm guessing "[buffer](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Transforming-Observables#buffer)" is the method that I need to be using. I whipped up a quick example in Android (code follows), but the buffer method doesn't seem to be as simple as just collect all event inputs and spit out a collection.

```
public class DemoFragment
    extends Fragment {

    private int _tapCount = 0;
    private Observable<List<Integer>> _bufferedObservable;
    private Observer<List<Integer>> _observer;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        _setupLogger();

        _bufferedObservable = _getBufferedObservable();
        _observer = _getObserver();
    }


    // the library butterknife allows this
    @OnClick(R.id.btn_start_operation)
    public void onButtonTapped() {
        _log("GOT A TAP");
        _bufferedObservable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                         .subscribe(_observer);
    }

    private Observable<List<Integer>> _getBufferedObservable() {
        return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<Integer>() {


            @Override
            public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
                subscriber.onNext(1);   // send one tap here
            }

        }).buffer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // collect all taps in the last 2s
    }

    private Observer<List<Integer>> _getObserver() {
        return new Observer<List<Integer>>() {


            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                _log(String.format("%d taps", _tapCount));
                _tapCount = 0; // reset tap count
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {}

            @Override
            public void onNext(List<Integer> integers) {
                if (integers.size() > 0) {
                    for (int i : integers) {
                        _tapCount += i;
                    }
                    onCompleted();
                } else {
                    _log("No taps received");
                }
            }
        };
    }

    // ... other method that help wiring up the example (irrelevant to RxJava)
}
```

Can anyone help me understand the misconception in my understanding here?

**Problem 1**: I'm expecting `_getObserver()`'s `onNext` to send me a list with the accumulated number of taps. So if the button was hit 5 times, then i'm expecting a List with 5 items, each of which have the value "1". With the existing code, i'm always getting an empty list.

**Problem 2**: I basically do a console log if no events were received by checking `List<Integer> integers` size. If list is not empty, i throw in a console log, saying "not taps received". It appears that the Observable NEVER stops. It's almost like a timer, where it constantly keeps going on and on, even when no button tap was registered. Is there way to stop the Observable, if no event was registered in the last 10s?

**Problem 3**: The number of emits seem to almost exponentially increase. It's almost like its gathering the button empty taps from all previous times.

Comment: Which one? 'Buffer' isn't an operator,for a start.

Comment: [RxJava tests](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/blob/master/rxjava-core/src/test/java/rx/internal/operators/OperatorBufferTest.java) suggest buffer being an operator.

Comment: No it doesn't. There seems to be a thing called an 'operator buffer', but that doesn't translate to 'buffer is the operator I should be using'. buffer() is a *method* in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a code showing how I would do it (assuming your button's id is `R.id.rx_button`):

```
private Subscription mSubscription;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSubscription = Observable.create(new OnSubscribe<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) {
            findViewById(R.id.rx_button).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    subscriber.onNext(1);
                }
            });
        }
    }).buffer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe(new Action1<List<Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(List<Integer> integers) {
                    Log.i("TAG", String.valueOf(integers.size()));
                }
            });
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mSubscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Simply put, just close the `OnClickListener` implementation over the `call` method, so you will be able to use the `subscriber` object inside it.

The `onResume` will look even better with lambdas (take a look on the Retrolambda project):

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSubscription = Observable.create((Subscriber<? super Integer> subscriber) ->
            findViewById(R.id.rx_button).setOnClickListener(view ->
                    subscriber.onNext(1))).buffer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .subscribe(integers -> Log.i("TAG", String.valueOf(integers.size())));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tomrozb, I finally got around to trying it. I got it working also in an alternate way (using a PublishSubject), but your solution for this particular case is definitely much more elegant.

Answer (score 1):

I think its best to use the awesome [rx-binding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) library for that. The solution is cleaner I think, especially with lambdas. I used the filter operator so I only get results in onNext() where the user pressed more than 5 times within the given 2 seconds.

I based this on an example from ([RxJava-Android-Samples](https://github.com/kaushikgopal/RxJava-Android-Samples)) which uses an old rx-binding dependency.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mClickSubscription = getBufferedSubscription();
}

@Override 
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mClickSubscription.unsubscribe();
} 

private Subscription getBufferedSubscription() {
    return RxView.clicks(rx_button)
            .map(aVoid -> 1)
            .buffer(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .filter(integers -> integers.size() > 5)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<Integer>>() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    // fyi: you'll never reach here
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    SLog.i("Dang error! check your logs");
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(List<Integer> integers) {
                    SLog.i(String.format("%d taps", integers.size()));

                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try bellow code :

```
public class BufferExampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = BufferExampleActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    Button btn;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_example);
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                doSomeWork();
            }
        });
    }

    /*
     * simple example using buffer operator - bundles all emitted values into a list
     */
    private void doSomeWork() {

        Observable<List<String>> buffered = getObservable().buffer(3, 1);

        // 3 means,  it takes max of three from its start index and create list
        // 1 means, it jumps one step every time
        // so the it gives the following list
        // 1 - one, two, three
        // 2 - two, three, four
        // 3 - three, four, five
        // 4 - four, five
        // 5 - five

        buffered.subscribe(getObserver());
    }

    private Observable<String> getObservable() {
        return Observable.just("one", "two", "three", "four", "five");
    }

    private Observer<List<String>> getObserver() {
        return new Observer<List<String>>() {

            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                Log.d(TAG, " onSubscribe : " + d.isDisposed());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(List<String> stringList) {
                textView.append(" onNext size : " + stringList.size());
                textView.append(AppConstant.LINE_SEPARATOR);
                Log.d(TAG, " onNext : size :" + stringList.size());
                for (String value : stringList) {
                    textView.append(" value : " + value);
                    textView.append(AppConstant.LINE_SEPARATOR);
                    Log.d(TAG, " : value :" + value);
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                textView.append(" onError : " + e.getMessage());
                textView.append(AppConstant.LINE_SEPARATOR);
                Log.d(TAG, " onError : " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                textView.append(" onComplete");
                textView.append(AppConstant.LINE_SEPARATOR);
                Log.d(TAG, " onComplete");
            }
        };
    }
}
```